Double value dont pass in if condition
I am trying to check candle high,low, open and close for gold in mql5. in if condition it pass only both are same, other wise none are passing through.
i have print value and it's all ok, below are the value for all 4.

2024.12.26 11:51:32.207 2024.12.24 00:00:00   prevOpen----2615.7 2024.12.26 11:51:32.207  2024.12.24 00:00:00   prevClose----2615.53 2024.12.26 11:51:32.207  2024.12.24 00:00:00   prevHigh----2615.67 2024.12.26 11:51:32.207   2024.12.24 00:00:00   prevLow----2615.44

   double prevOpen = NormalizeDouble(iOpen(Symbol(), PERIOD_M1, 1),4);
   double prevClose = NormalizeDouble(iClose(Symbol(), PERIOD_M1, 1), 4);
   double prevHigh = NormalizeDouble(iHigh(Symbol(), PERIOD_M1, 1), 4);
   double prevLow = NormalizeDouble(iLow(Symbol(), PERIOD_M1, 1), 4);

   if(NormalizeDouble(prevClose,_Digits) >= NormalizeDouble(prevHigh,_Digits))
     {
      tookUpperLiquidity = true;
      tookLowerLiquidity = false;
     }
   else if(NormalizeDouble(prevClose,_Digits) <= NormalizeDouble(prevLow,_Digits))
     {
       tookLowerLiquidity = true;
       tookUpperLiquidity = false;
     }

why is it so? how do i compare double value or there are alternative ways to do it?
